# Formatting \DTMuseDate with a custom format

Tags: formatting, datetime2

I created a custom format and saved a date like this:

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime2}
\DTMnewdatestyle{dateMonat}{\THEDAY. \monthnamengerman[\THEMONTH]}
\DTMsavedate{dateABC}{2023-07-20}
```

I want to display my date with my custom format. This would have been done like this in datetime

```
\dateMonat\today
```

Nothing similar works in datetime2.
I suspect i will have to use `\DTMuseDate` to use `dateABC`

Setting the formatting before a section `\DTMsetdatestyle{dateMonat}` is not an option i like since the format often changes even in the same line.

Is there a better way? Or do i have to `\DTMsetdatestyle{dateMonat}` before every displayed date?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problems i had:

1. My style of formatting dates was very wrong. The new style for datetime2 is as follows

```
\DTMnewdatestyle{dateMonat}{%
\renewcommand{\DTMdisplaydate}[4]{\number##3. \DTMgermanmonthname{\number##2}}%
\renewcommand{\DTMDisplaydate}{\DTMdisplaydate}%
}
```

2. The way i did not like is still the correct way:

```
\DTMsetdatestyle{dateMonat}\DTMusedate{dateABC}
```

One would still have to redo this for every date